# How to sort a dictionary list with multiple values related to one single key name and convert it to float numbers

Tags: python, csv, floating-point, sorteddictionary

I'm a beginner at Python and I'm trying to figure out a paper I have to do for school. So the situation is that I have a `csvfile` under `DictReader` and want to be able to not only sort all the values related to one key in the dictionary, which is 'CRIM', in ascending order, but also to convert all the data values in float so I can more easily manipulate the information after that

The CSV file data looks like this: `{"CRIM": "0,00522"} {"CRIM": "0,06552"} {"CRIM": "0,01903"} {"CRIM": "0,01263"}`

I started doing this:

```py
import csv

with open('data. Question 1.csv', newline='') as csvfile:

  data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
  
  for line in data:

    list_values = (line['CRIM'])
```

This makes all the values related to the Key 'CRIM' appear but don't know how to proceed from there.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please, provide how the expected output dictionary should look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the a list of all of the float "CRIM" values, you can try this. This assumes that "CRIM" appears in every line, and each float value follows the same format as your sample data.

```
import csv

list_values = []
with open('data. Question 1.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for line in data:
        list_values.append(float(line['CRIM'].replace(',','.')))
list_values.sort()
```

Comment: It solves the problem in the way it was needed to be solve, thank you!